# some question about base extension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let f: X -> Y be universally open surjective morphism of finite algebraic schemes.

Let Y' -> Y be a base extension and let f':x' -> Y' be the extended morphism.
Then the image of every component of X' is a component of Y'.

Why? Is it ok because "f is open"?

Answer (score 1):

A morphism between finite schemes is finite itself (EGA II, 6.1.5 (v)), so $f'$ is finite as well, hence closed (EGA II, 6.1.10). Now apply EGA IV, 2.3.5 (ii).